# Why redirecting cmd error to file doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, error-handling

The thing is that redirecting errors to the file in command line doesn't work. I will explain this by giving an example.

`ping /wrong > output.txt 2> error.err`

produces **empty error.err** file and **output.txt with error text** . That's huge surprice since this synthax is given in MS docs and literally everywhere over the web.

Using `>>` instead of `>` with `2>>` instead of `2>` doesn't change command line behaviour. I've also tried running it as script with `.cmd` extension, running with command line in admin mode and none of this help.

Moreover,  `ping /wrong 2> error.err` ends up with error apearing in console (which doesn't happened in previous example since it was redirected). Any thoughts?

Comment: This errormessage is indeed output on STDOUT. (I agree, it *should*  be on STDERR, but in the end, it is (or better was) the developer's choice.)

Comment: `ping` is strange in more than this issue. If you ping a non-existent IP in your local network, you get something like "reply from <localhost>: destination not reachable", which is a positive reply (although not from the pinged host) and `%errorlevel%` gives `0`, indicating "success".

Comment: Maybe I should mentioned that I've also tried with forcing 'Access denied' error (attempt to write to read-only file) and with copying not existing file - all ends up like above.

Answer (score 2):

`ping` being a diagnostics tool, only always sends results to `stdout` stream because of, seemingly, that very reason (Developers choice as stated by @Stephan).
The end result however will set an `exitcode` of off the `errorlevel` which can be used accordingly if required.

So given this known example:

```
ping somehost && echo Success || echo Failed
```

Would use the `errorlevel` to determine the correct path, either it was successfully, or it failed. So you can simply utilize that ability to perform a little hack:

```
ping somehost >hold.tmp && type hold.tmp>output.txt || type hold.tmp>error.err
del /Q hold.tmp>nul 2>&1
```

Comment: Is this the same case with the mentioned above copy and echo (to the restricted file)?

Comment: no, it simply stores the original `stdout` result in a temp file, the errorlevel or exitcode then gets evaluated by the conditional operators and we simply force the output to the file based on the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
@echo off
ping somehost >[file]
```

It works on Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: (don't use 2> instead!)

Comment: (also don't use 2>>)                                                                                                     i've used .bat extension.